# Concerning Using Custom Fonts [Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method]

Tags: java, fonts, awt

I usually try not to ask questions that I've seen before, but this is different. I've been trying to get my custom font to work, but whenever I try to use it in a method, I get the error "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method". I know what that means, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Here's the example -

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class AddFont extends MainFrame{
public void createFont() throws Exception {

InputStream telegraficoFontAdd = AddFont.class.getResourceAsStream(FONT_PATH_TELEGRAFICO);
    Font telegraficoFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT,telegraficoFontAdd);
    telegraficoFont = telegraficoFont.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN,20);
    GraphicsEnvironment ge =
        GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    ge.registerFont(telegraficoFont);
    }
}
```

That's my AddFont class file, here is the snippet of my MainFrame -

```
      public static void main(String[] args) {
  javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
        try {
            AddFont addFont = new AddFont();
            addFont.createFont();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        createGUI();

     } //public void run() Closing
  });
}
```

How would I find a way to use the method class in static objects, because I have a long list of buttons I need to change the fonts for? 
Or is there some work-around that I must do?

And as always, if you downvote this, please tell me why, so I will know how to improve. Hopefully this is considered an SSCCE.

EDIT - Changed my main method in my MainFrame, now I get the error -

```
java.io.IOException: Problem reading font data.
at java.awt.Font.createFont(Unknown Source)
at AddFont.createFont(AddFont.java:11)
at MainFrame$1.run(MainFrame.java:107)
```

(Line 11 in my  AddFont file is this -

```
  Font telegraficoFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT,telegraficoFontAdd);
```

and Line 107 of my MainFrame is

```
 addFont.createFont();
```

Comment: *"Hopefully this is considered an SSCCE."*  An SSCCE is one source file, as opposed to one source file & a code snippet.  And since I'm here.. 1) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 2) There is never a need for more than blank one line of white space in source.

Comment: `AddFont.createFont();` <- you are making a static reference to a non-static method. Fix that and your g2g.

Comment: To Ravi Tridedi, I know what the problem is. But my main method is static. I want to know if there is a way to change the font class to work with static methods without having to change all of my methods/classes.

To Andrew Thompson, I'll try to edit my post so it's just one file, not 2. The two blank likes under createGUI(); I never edited out were accidental, sorry.

Comment: @Hathor, Create an `Object` of your class and then call method `createFont()`. Check out the answer.

Comment: @RaviTrivedi I made an edit to my main post, may you take a look at my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function `public void createFont()` needs to be static if you are planning to call your function using your `Class` name.

Make it `public static void createFont()`

If you don't want to use `static` then simply create `Object` of your class and then call as below:

```
AddFont addFont = new AddFont();
addFont.createFont();
```